# Pouchdb / CouchDB all_docs error

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm setting up a pouchdb / couchdb live sync.  I'm using [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) to login.

When on my local dev server, everything works fine.

```
  let pdbConfig = { skipSetup: true}; 
  let remoteDb : any = new PouchDB(config.couch.server, pdbConfig);
  remoteDb.login(config.couch.username, config.couch.password).then(u => {
    db.sync(remoteDb, {
      live: true
    }).on('complete', (info)=> {
      store.dispatch({type: "REMOTE_SYNC_COMPLETE"});
    })

  }).catch(e=>{
    console.error(e)
  })
```

On production, I receive this error:

```
{"error":"case_clause","reason":"{forbidden,<<\"You are not a db or server admin.\">>}"}
```

Request URL:  https://myproductionserver:6984/userdb-82911660-c14b-472c-adb4-6f2ed280cae9/_all_docs?conflicts=true&include_docs=true

I've noticed that this only happens when a new sync occurs (otherwise it does not appear `all_docs` is called)  `all_docs` doesn't appear to be called at all on my local dev server, regardless of state.

Other calls (to _session, _changes) etc work fine to the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like users need to have admin permissions on a database to use `all_docs`.  My users were only "members.    `all_docs` isn't called in pouchdb unless a database already exists on the couchdb server, but not on the client.